# Problem finding elements by class with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the name of the events on this page, using beautiful soup 4 : https://www.orbitxch.com/customer/sport/1

I tried to filter the html code for tags with class="biab_item-link biab_market-link js-event-link biab_has-time", has it seemed to be the ones containing each unique event name once.

Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3


http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = 'https://www.orbitxch.com/customer/sport/1'
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, features="lxml")



for tag in soup.find_all("a", class_="biab_item-link biab_market-link js-event-link biab_has-time"):
        print(tag["title"])
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because html content is dynamically changed by javascript. Data came from this URL: https://www.orbitxch.com/customer/api/event-updates?eventIds=29108154,29106937,29096310,29096315,29106936,29096313,29096309,29096306,29107821,29108318,29106488,29106934,29106830,29106490,29104420   but honestly I don't know where can you find these IDs. This URL returns JSON response which you can easily parse using Python library.

Comment: Thanks. How did you find the url it came from ? So my best bet would be to parse this JSON or there is an easier way ?

Comment: @Clipper I found this using Firefox developing tools, concretely network statistics (Chrome has these tools too). JSON parsing will be the easiest way, you had python library for it but to ids in url can change, you have to find out where does javascript code find these ids.

Comment: You might also consider using [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org) which allows loading the full page and then parsing it, which http library doesn't.

Comment: @InfectedDrake That's a very good point, I didn't know about this library. Maybe I will use this library sometime in the future but I still more prefer making requests to correct site which contains wanted data.